# One taxonomy filtering two fields

Tags: views

I have 2 fields on one node that both read the same taxonomy (Normal features and special features).

Now I want to show only 1 filter in the view that looks in both fields. And with the "Combined fields" filter I don't get these fields as an option, let alone only get a text field and no checkboxes